# How do I set a limit for a variable in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, random, while-loop, blackjack

```
import random

dealer = random.randint(10, 21)
begin = random.randint(1, 14)
card = random.randint(1, 14)
limit = int(21)
print(begin)
i = input('Hit or Stay?').lower()

while i == "hit":
    begin += random.randint(1, 14)
    print(begin)
    i = input('Hit or Stay?').lower()

if begin == 21:
    print('Wow, you win!')
elif i == "stay":
    if dealer >= begin:
        print('You lose')
        print(dealer)
    else:
        print('You win')
        print(dealer)
elif begin >= limit:
    print('You lose')
```

I'm currently trying to make a 21 blackjack game(my own twist ofc).
However, I've come across a problem. The rules in blackjack is that if your hand goes over the number 21, you lose. I'm having trouble doing that. Currently, python only prints "you lose!" when the player goes over the number 21 and then stays his hand.
Current Output when Reaching 21/Winning:

```
Starting Hand: 13
Hit or Stay?hit
Current Hand: 15
Hit or Stay?hit
Current Hand: 21
Hit or Stay?stay
Wow, you win!
```

Expected Output:

```
Starting Hand: 13
Hit or Stay?hit
Current Hand: 21 
You Win!!!
```

Current Output for Going Past 21:

```
Starting Hand:  4
Hit or Stay?hit
Current Hand:  13
Hit or Stay?hit
Current Hand:  24
Hit or Stay?stay
You lose because you went over 21 haha
```

Expected Output:

```
Starting Hand: 20
Hit or Stay?hit
Current Hand: 25
You lose because you went over 21 hahaha
```

I hope someone will be able to fix my code :<

Comment: You can add a condition inside the for loop which checks if the number is <= 21 or not. if not, it will print you lose and break the whole loop, else continue. And since when you enter stay you get out of the while loop, you can check then the dealer hand before checking and printing win condition? Is this making any sense ?

Comment: Shouldn't the if-else block be indented, so it will be inside the while block?

Comment: I know you said it was your "own twist" of Blackjack, but shouldn't you account for aces (1, or 11) and face-cards all being worth 10 points each? Also as a side-note, in your current sollution, aces have a higher chance of being picked than any other card.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import random

def check(begin):
    is_end = True
    if begin == 21:
        print('Wow, you win!')
    elif i == "stay":
        if dealer >= begin:
            print('You lose')
            print(dealer)
        else:
            print('You win')
            print(dealer)
    elif begin >= limit:
        print('You lose')
    else:
        is_end=False
    return is_end

dealer = random.randint(10, 21)
begin = random.randint(1, 14)
card = random.randint(1, 14)
limit = int(21)
print(begin)
i = input('Hit or Stay?').lower()

while i == "hit":
    begin += random.randint(1, 14)
    print(begin)
    if check(begin):
        break
    i = input('Hit or Stay?').lower()
```

Comment: This works but can you explain to me how it works? What does def check do? Edit: The stay command no longer works. It just finishes the process.

Answer (score 1):

```
import random

dealer = random.randint(10, 21)
begin = random.randint(1, 14)
card = random.randint(1, 14)
limit = int(21)
print(begin)

i = input('Hit or Stay?').lower()

while begin < limit:
    begin += random.randint(1, 14)
    print(begin)
    i = input('Hit or Stay?').lower()

    if begin == limit:
      print('You win')
    else:
      print('You lose')
      break
```